If anyone complete a puruscharna/anusthan of any mantra, do he need to chant that mantra daily? Is it necessary? Or any alternative options available
If anyone complete a puruscharna/anusthan of any mantra, do he need to chant that mantra daily? Is it necessary?

I) Kulārnava Tantram describes Purascharana (पुरश्चरण) as Tantra Upāsana (तन्त्र उपासना/Practice of Tantra) which consists of five angas (अङ्ग/Parts) viz., Tri-kāla Pūja (त्रिकाल पूजा), Japa (जप ), Havana(हवन), Tarpana(तर्पणं), and Bhojana (भोजणं) respectively as follows:
पूजा त्रिकालिकी नित्यं जपस्तर्पणमेव च।
होमो ब्राह्मणभुक्तिश्च पुरश्चरणमच्यते ॥ ८ ॥ 
यद् यदङ्गं विहीयेत तत्संख्याद्विगुणो जपः।
कुर्याद् द्वित्रिचतुःपञ्च-संख्यां वा साधकः प्रिये ॥ ९ ॥  
कुर्वीत चाङ्गसिद्ध्यर्थं तदशक्तौ स भक्तितः।
तच्चेदङ्गं विहीयेत मन्त्री नेष्ट मवाप्नुयात् ॥ १०॥

Purascharana has five angas which are (i) daily pūja [त्रिकाल पूजा/at
the three prescribed hours: in the morning, noon and evening],
(ii) japa, (iii) tarpana [offering of libation], (iv) homa and 
(v) brāhmana bhojanam [feeding the brāhmanās]. If any of these limbs 
are lacking, make up for it, with appropriate increase of japa as prescribed.
Without this compensation Mantra Siddhi is not achieved and
Purascharana is not considered to be complete.

— Kulārnava Tantram [Chapter-15 Slokas: 8 - 10].

II) Viswasāra Tantram (विश्वसार तंत्र/விசுவஸார தந்திரம்): Viswasāra Tantram describes Purascharana (पुरश्चरण) as Tantra Upāsana (तन्त्र उपासना/Practice of Tantra) which consists of five angas (अङ्ग/Parts) viz., (i) Japa Vidhānam(जप विदानम्), (ii) Havana(हवन), (iii) Tarpana(तर्पणं), (iv) Mārjana (मार्जणं) and (v) Bhojana (भोजणं) respectively. The Moola Mantra Japa (मूल मन्त्र जप) constitutes the mukya anga (मुख्य अङ्ग/Principal part) of the tantra upāsana. Most of sadakās (सादक/Practitioner/Aspirant) ignore the other four angas but sticking only to Japa which demonstrates it importance in the process of attaining Mantra Siddhi (मन्त्र सिद्धि).
III) Mantramahodadhi (मन्त्रमहोदधि/மந்த்ரமஹோததி்): Mantramahodadhi Tantra Granta describes Purascharana (पुरश्चरण) for Tantra Upāsana (तन्त्र उपासना/Practice of Tantra) which consists of two angas (अङ्ग/Parts) viz., Japa (जप विदानम्) and Havana(हवन) respectively.

प्रत्यहम् प्रत्यहम् तावन्नैव न्यूनाधिकम् क्वचित्। एवम् जपम्
समाप्यान्ते दशांशं होममाचरेत्॥
Every-day the number of Japas should be kept the same as predetermined
in the sankalpa and then havana should be performed one-tenth
(dasāmsa) of the number of Japa.
For instance number of japa is 100 then the number of havana should be
10 and so on.
Note: The Number of havana does not imply multiple havana sessions. It
means the number of Ahutis(आहुति/Suitable dravya-द्रव्य which varies
according to Upāsanā Devatha) thrown into fire in a single havana
session.
— Mantramahodadhi 1.110


Summarizing (I), (II) and (III), the Procedure of Purascharana (पुरश्चरण) is given below. Depending on aspirant’s the school of tantra, the anga of Purascharana will vary.

For Kulārnava Tantram (कुलार्णव तंत्र) the five angas (parts) of Purascharana will be Tri-kāla pūja, Japa, havana, tarpana and brahmana bhojanam.
For Viswasāra Tantram (विश्वसार तंत्र) the five angas (parts) of Purascharana will be japa, havana, tarpana, mārjana and brāhmana bhojanam.
Those who follow Mantramahodadhi (मन्त्रमहोदधि), will carry out Purascharana consisting of only two angas which are japa and Havana respectively.


This Devatha Upāsana should be performed everyday or according to a solid time table. Based on your focus, dedication and perseverance you will taste success (Devatha Vasyam/देवता वश्यम्). This may take few weeks or few years, all in your hands particularly upon your Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म) in this birth.
Kulārnava Tantra [chapter-15] speaks about conditions conducive to the success of japa as follows [sloka-113]:
तन्निष्ठस्तद्गतप्राणस्तच्चित्तस्तत्परायणः । 
तत्पदाथनुसन्धानं कुर्वन्‌ मनर जपेत्‌ प्रिये ॥ ११३ ॥ 

One should perform Japa with devotion to the Mantra, with life
dedicated to it, with mind centred upon it, wholly given to it,
following its meaning and meditating upon it.॥ 113 ॥


Your question If anyone complete a puruscharna/anusthan of any mantra, do he need to chant that mantra daily? Is it necessary?
No, you need not have to do japa daily after acquiring mantra dāksha. The question is if you can't carry out Purashcharana every day, then what for did you obtain mantra dāksha? Please know that tantra sādhana is a serious business.
Mantra Mahodadhi [Chapter-24] says about what to do when Purashcharana is unsuccessful:
पुरश्चण एकस्मिन्कृते जन्मान्तराघतः | 
मन्त्रो यदि न सिद्धः स्यात्तदा तत्पुनराचरेत्‌ ॥ १२६॥

If by performing Purashcharana (पुरश्चरण), once the mantra does not
fructify due to sin of past past births, the sadhaka should repeat the
Purashcharana.॥ 126 ॥

Beware-1: This is the general complaint from sādhaka that even after completing the prescribed count of Japa if the mantra did not fructify then sādhaka should repeat Purashcharana until fructification of mantra. The reason is due to the karma of past births.
Beware-2: Kulārnava Tantra [chapter-15, sloka-100] describes Obstructive factors in the success of Japa is:
मनोऽन्यत्र शिवोऽन्यत्र शक्तिरन्यत्र मारुतः । 
न सिध्यति वरारोहे लक्षकोटिजपादपि ॥ १००॥ 

If the mind be in one place, Siva [passive consciousness] in another,
Sakti [active consciousness] in another and the life-breath in still
another, then even a crore of Japa, O Varārohe, would be useless.॥ 100॥

In order to expedite mantra fructification, it is wise to utilize the phenomenon such as solar and lunar eclipses without missing and perform purascarana during the entire period of eclipse. Mantra Mahodadhi [Chapter-24] says the following:
यद्वा समुद्रगामिन्यां नद्याभिन्दुरविग्रहे ।
स्पर्शान्मोक्षान्तमाजप्य जुहुयात्तद्दशांशत: ॥ १३०॥
विप्रान्सम्भोज्य नानान्नैर्मन्त्राणां सिद्धिमाप्नुयात्‌ ।
शश्वज्जपपरस्यापि सिध्यन्ति मनवोऽचिरात्‌ ॥ १३१॥  

At the time of solar or lunar eclipse, standing navel deep in some
river which falls in the ocean, the sādhaka should perform japa of
the Moola-mantra from the moment of touching of the eclipse till it
complete end. Then, perform Homa, 1/10th of the japa, and further
1/10th of Homa, feeding the Brāhmanās with various delicious food,
completes purascarana which bestows fructification. The mantras of a
person who performs incessant japa, also fructifies quickly. ॥ 130-131॥

Conclusion:
No Tantra Granta imposes any time-schedule to carry out puruscharna; it is in your hands totally. You are free to draw a schedule based on your busyness but stick to it strictly without slipping. However, Kulārnava Tantram [chapter-15] throws some general tips to taste success in japa:
शान्तः शुचिमिताहारो भूशायी भक्तिमान्‌ वशी । 
निर्हन्धः स्थिरधीमौनी संयतात्मा जपेत्‌ प्रिये ॥ ९९० ॥ 

One should be calm, clean, limited in food intake, sleeping on the
ground, devoted, in full control, free from duality, steady of mind,
silent and self-controlled during Japa. ॥ 110 ॥

विश्वासास्तिक््यकरुणाश्रद्धानियमनिश्चयैः । 
सन्तोषौत्सुक्यधमदिगुणैर्यक्तो जपेन्नरः ॥ ९९९ ॥

One should perform Japa with confidence, belief, composure, faith,
regularity, certitude, contentment, enthusiasm and like qualities.॥ 111 ॥

जपात्‌ श्रान्तः पुनर्ध्यायेद्धयानात्‌ श्रान्तः पुनर्जपेत्‌ । 
जपध्यानादियुक्तस्य क्षिप्र मन्त्रः प्रसिध्यति ॥ ११४ ॥ 

When tired by Japa, take to Dhyāna; tired in Dyāna, take again to
Japa. One who does both Japa and Dhyāna, achieves success in Mantras
very soon.॥ 114 ॥

Kulārnava Tantram [chapter-15] talks about don'ts while doing japa:
मलिनाम्बरकेशादिमुखदौर्गन्धसयुतः । 
यो जपेत्तं दहत्याशु देवता सुजुगुप्सिता ॥ ९०५ ॥ 

One who makes Japa with soiled cloth, soiled hairs, bad odour of mouth
or his person, then the Deity, being disgusted with him, burns him up
in a moment.॥ 105 ॥

आलस्यं ज॒म्भणं निद्रा क्षुतं निष्ठीवनं भयम्‌ । 
नीचाङ्गस्पनं कोपं जपकाले विवर्जयेत्‌ ॥ ९०६ ॥

One should avoid laziness, yawning, sleeping, sneezing, spitting,
fear, touching the lower limbs and anger.॥ 106 ॥

अत्याहारः प्रलापश्च प्रजल्पो नियमाग्रहः । 
अन्यासङ्गश्च लौल्यञ्च षड्भिर्मन्त्रो न सिध्यति ॥ ९०७ ॥ 

The Mantra does not succeed where there is excessive food, meaningless
talk, gossip, rigidity of rules, attachment to another and
fickleness.॥ 107 ॥

उष्णीशी कञ्चुकी नग्नो मुक्तकेशो गणावृतः । 
अपवित्रोत्तरीयश्चाशुचिर्गच्छश्च नो जपेत्‌ ॥ १०८ ॥ 

One should not perform Japa with his turban on, with cloak, naked,
hair disheveled, surrounded by retinue, unclean upper cloth or while
impure or while walking.॥ 108 ॥

जाड्यं दुःखं तृणच्छेदं विवादं वा मनोरथम्‌ । 
बहिस्तु देहवायुञ्च जपकाले विवर्जयेत्‌ ॥ ९०९ ॥

One should avoid during Japa inertia, grief, useless activity, free
imagination and passing of wind. ॥ 109 ॥

Good Luck!
